# How do I execute a function every 3 months?

Tags: 7, cron, log-messages

What's the proper way to execute a function every 3 months? Watchdog variables don't seem to be available after a certain time. I could create another table to insert the execute function date to compare, but it doesn't seem to be the best approach.

The functionality of such functions are:

- Send an eMail
- Tag an inactive user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`watchdog()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7.x) is not appropriate place for storage; the `$variables` parameter is for formatting the display of variable data (e.g. the *USERNAME* in "User *USERNAME* has logged in"), not for long term storage of application data.

Instead, use a combination of [`hook_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7.x) and the persistent variable functions ([`variable_get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7.x) and [`variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7.x)) to execute a cron task that remembers when it was last run.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_cron().
 */
function MYMODULE_cron() {

  // Look up last time MYMODULE_function() was run compared to 3 months ago.
  if (variable_get('MYMODULE_function_last_run', 0) <= strtotime('-3 month')) {
     // Run my function
     MYMODULE_function();

     //Store the time when MYMODULE_function() was last run.
     variable_set('MYMODULE_function_last_run', time());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module together with `Rules Scheduler` (a sub-module of it), can be used for executing functions such as ***sending eMails*** (as in your comment below the question), as explained in the steps below,.

#### Step 1: Create a field to store the "next renewal" date

Add a field to the "user" entity with machine name (say) `field_next_renewal`. Allow only 1 date (to store the "next" date for a sending an eMail to some user, eg about some renewal).

#### Step 2: Create a Rules "Component"

Here is the Rules **Component** to be created (in Rules export format, just import it in your own environment via copy-paste):

```
{ "rules_send_email_notification" : {
    "LABEL" : "Send eMail notification",
    "PLUGIN" : "action set",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "user_to_notify" : { "label" : "User to be notified", "type" : "user" } },
    "ACTION SET" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : [ "user-to-notify:mail" ],
          "subject" : "Reminder about your next renewal",
          "message" : "This is a reminder about your next renewal on [user-to-notify:field_next_renewal] ...",
          "from" : "[site:mail]",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Obviously, the ***Subject*** and ***Content*** of the eMail may need review / tuning, while you might also want to use some other ***From*** eMail ID.

#### Step 3: Create a "Rule" using the Rules Component

Here is the **Rule** to be created, in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format (just import it in your own environment via copy-paste):

```
{ "rules_email_user_every_3_months" : {
    "LABEL" : "eMail user every 3 months",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_scheduler" ],
    "ON" : { "user_insert" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "account" ], "field" : "field_next_renewal" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "account:field-next-renewal" ], "value" : "+6 month" } },
      { "schedule" : {
          "component" : "rules_send_email_notification",
          "date" : {
            "select" : "account:field-next-renewal",
            "date_offset" : { "value" : 7776000 }
          },
          "identifier" : "[account:name]",
          "param_user_to_notify" : [ "account" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The above rule refers to the *Rules Component* from the previous step.

Note that the `7776000` is the equivalent of 3 months in seconds. You may want to reduce that a bit, e.g. with a number of seconds equivalent to a few days (or a week or so). That way the eMail will be triggered a few days before the actual renewal.

#### Step 4: tagging inactive users

By creating an extra rule similar to the rule in step 3, you could also "flag" inactive user using the integration of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) with the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module. That would be a solution for ***tagging such users*** (as in your comment below the question) also. The only remaining challenge about that would be to find the Rules Condition to identify "*inactive*" users.

Comment: I suppose, that if I trigger a Rule to send eMail to inactive users, it will be possible to identify who was inactive at a certain date?

Comment: I cannot answer "that" yet, first I need to know what "you" consider as "inactive" for a user. Can you explain what you call "inactive"? Like is it "last login date is at least X days or months ago"?

Comment: The purpose of this function is to identify all users who were inactive on the site for the last 3 months, send an email to notify, and after 1 week, if that user doesn't enter the site, proceed to delete his account.

Comment: OK, this extra comment makes it a little more clear, but: **(1)** that's really like a new question, why not post a new question about that (also because changing the content of a question to a new question is not allowed according to the rules on this site, which I did not invent ...) and **(2)** since you marked Shawn's answer as accepted, I assume Shawn's answer is an answer to your original question here and **(3)** repeat from my prior comment (which you still did not answer, sorry): ***Can you explain what you call "inactive"?***

Comment: I was searching for a simple functionality that trigger a function after 3 months, but after reading your answer, I saw a lot more possibilities, that is why I was going more deep on my prior question. You probably are right, I should posted it as another question. In order to at least answer your question, I mark a User as inactive, before 3 months without a login on the site.

Comment: OK, "now" I understand what "you" call an active user (which makes sense). Good to know that my additional answer inspired you somehow to see more possibilities. I suggest you post like a followup question (eventually referring to this answer if you need/want). But make sure to not make it a too broad question (to avoid a valid/complete answer would be like writing a manual). Or do you think I should post my own question with a summary of some of your comments here, and post my own answer (with about 4 steps ...) to it also?